# Lombok annotations require entire rebuild in IntelliJ before application run

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I'm using Lombok annotations for logging, getters, setters etc. My code won't compile before a complete rebuild of the application as it cannot resolve the respective annotations (e.g. with error `error: cannot find symbol` for an instance variable getter that has been defined with `lombok.Getter` (`@Getter` class annotation).

If I rebuild, it compiles & runs as expected. As it seemingly is not possible to add a `rebuild` task to 'before launch tasks' in IntelliJ (only `build`), this is rather annoying. I have annotation processing enabled in settings:

[IntelliJ Settings Annotation Processing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9QBC.png)

Using Lombok via Gradle plugin: `id("io.freefair.lombok") version "8.0.1"` on Java 19.

Lombok plugin for IntelliJ is enabled. Tried invalidating caches and restarting.

Is there a way to either automate rebuild before launch or rather avoid complete rebuild in the first place?

Trying to reduce boilerplate code using Lombok but the necessity of rebuilds is disrupting the workflow.

Comment: There is an intellij plugin for lombok which, I believe, just ships out-of-the-box with intellij; possibly you may have to turn it on.

Comment: This plugin does ship out-of-the-box and is enabled; disabling + enabling + restart also won't help.

Comment: sometimes intellij needs to "invalidate caches and restart" when it can't find symbols...

Comment: Thanks, but also already tried - does not help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.